# How to export datagridview with multiline into one cell in csv

Tags: c#, datagridview, export-to-csv

With code below, when I export my `datagridview` to excel, the code will only read the first line in the cell. Here is my [DTG image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkRXJ.png) and how it is exported to [CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrpQL.png). Below is my code:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var headers = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>();

sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", headers.Select(column => "\"" + column.HeaderText + "\"").ToArray()));

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   var cells = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>();
   sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", cells.Select(cell => "\"" + cell.Value + "\"").ToArray()));
 }

  string filepath = @"C:\Data.csv"; ;
  File.WriteAllText(filepath, sb.ToString());
```

When I changed the `,` into `;` or `|` for the cell values, it printed all the lines but the datas are jumbled up in different cells. Hope to get help, thanks.

**Edited:** Jumbled up per this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcEmz.png) is when I changed my line of code to be `sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", cells.Select(cell => "\"" + cell.Value + "\"").ToArray()));`. As per photo, the 2nd line onwards will go to another cell.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by jumbled up. The DTG and Excel looks pretty similar. Can you elaborate?

Comment: hai @kapd I have edited my code. Jumbled up in the sense where all the lines are printed ( both _hi_ and _bye_) but not in their respective headers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem starts with the `StringBuilder` and ends with the `File.WriteAllText`.

The `StringBuilder` interprets all line breaks and replaces them with `\r\n` and then the `File.WriteAllText` does exactly the same thing.
Interpreting all line breaks and add them to the file as a "real" line break.

You tried to put each value between two `"` which is common, but there is no rule that every program has to interpret it this way. So CSV-Files are not really supportive when it comes to line breaks or commas in the value, because most of the editors see a line break as a new row and a comma as a new column.

So the best way is to remove them or replace them with a custom string which everybody who is working with this file knows and can re-replace it then.

So that would be one option to do it:

```
cell.Value?.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "{BREAK}").Replace("\n", "{BREAK}")
```

---

**Edit 1:**

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var headers = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>();

sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", headers.Select(column => column.HeaderText).ToArray()));

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var cells = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>();
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", cells.Select(cell => cell.Value?.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "{BREAK}").Replace("\n", "{BREAK}")).ToArray()));
}

string filepath = "data.csv"; ;
File.WriteAllText(filepath, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: hi @bene_rawr, as per above, I've changed my line to be `sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", cells.Select(cell => cell.Value?.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "{BREAK}").Replace("\n", "{BREAK}").ToArray())));`. But now, the rows reflect as `System.Char[]` instead of actual data. Then when I want to convert char to string by writing `string s = new string(sb);`, I get and error **cannot convert from Text.Stringbuilder to char**. And I don't know how else to continue.

Comment: Mh.. without the full code I can't say that much. But I updated the answer with the complete example.

Comment: @hi bene_rawr. Ive tried your edited code but now the data becomes _hi{BREAK}bye_. I do not want the word {BREAK} to be there. Is that possible? And the code that Ive posted is the full code that exports DTG to CSV

Comment: As said before, you won't be able to create a CSV File with an actual linebreak., cause most programs which are able to read CSV use a linebreak as a new tupel (row). So you can remove it and just have it one line or you replace the line break and when you import them again you can re-replace them.

Comment: Hai @bene_rawr. Ok now fully understand what is it. Ultimately, I still have to use CSV. Thanks for your time.

Comment: When my answer was helpful and/or helped you, please mark it as the answer and give it an upvote. Thanks!